# Dependency version issue with Spring, Spring Neo4j and Neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to setup a Java project which uses Spring-Neo4j and Neo4j but unable to get around with dependency issues. I am using maven for dependency management and have tried several version combinations of Spring, Spring Neo4j and Neo4j.

spring: **3.2.6.RELEASE**

spring-data-neo4j: **3.0.0.RELEASE**

neo4j: **2.0.1**

**application-context.xml file**

```
<neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/graph.db" />
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.checkConfigurationAllowsAutomaticUpgrade(ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.java:39)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.attemptUpgrade(StoreUpgrader.java:71)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.tryToUpgradeStores(StoreFactory.java:144)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:119)
at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:323)
at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503)
... 64 more
```

I have enabled `allow_store_upgrade=true` in my `neo4j.properties` file.

Comment: Are you sure the data store has been cleanly shutdown with the old version prior to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Your embedded neo4j most likely doesn't pick up the neo4j file ([this](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-setup.html) documentation says you need to set it manually).

Initialise your neo4j like this

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"
        destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="target/config-test"/>
<!-- optionally pass in neo4j-config parameters to the graph database
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
-->
</bean>

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"/>
```

Source:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/setup.html#d0e3597

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to use spring-data-neo4j 3.1.1.RELEASE and neo4j 2.1.2 and I think this is incomplete. Indeed, at least with these versions, map is not optionnal. Moreover there is a third mandatory argument in constructor of type Dependencies.
The problem is that I don't really know what is this third parameter and moreover EmbeddedGraphDatabase and Dependecies are deprecated. Do you know which is the good way to start a webapp (with these versions) in embedded mode ?

Comment: @yatendra-goel Here is a good way to write spring configuration : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24928035/how-to-configure-a-neo4j-embeddedgraphdatabase-now-deprecated-with-spring-data)