# how to configure a neo4j EmbeddedGraphDatabase (now deprecated) with spring-data-neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I'm using spring-data-neo4j 3.1.1.Release with neo4j 2.1.2. I managed to make a spring configuration which is working well but it use the org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase class which is now deprecated. Here is my current configuration :

```
<bean id="graphDatabaseService" class="org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase"
      destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${graphdir}"/>
    <!-- optionally pass in neo4j-config parameters to the graph database -->
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <map>
            <entry key="allow_store_upgrade" value="true"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="defaultGraphDatabaseDependencies" />
</bean>

<bean id="defaultGraphDatabaseDependencies" class="org.neo4j.kernel.DefaultGraphDatabaseDependencies"/>

<neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"  base-package="com.company.domain"/>
```

How can I write the same kind of spring configuration but using non deprecated classes please ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the GraphDatabaseFactory class using spring for this. I've blogged about at http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2013/08/configuring-a-neo4j-graphdatabaseservice-via-spring/

Comment: Nice it works very well, thank you. For other users, just don't forget to add <neo4j:config graphDatabaseService="graphDatabaseService"  base-package="your.domain.package"/> to create the neo4jTemplate bean